# HTML-mode insert tag without attribute(s)

Tags: html, ivy

In HTML-mode `C-c C-o` is bound to `sgml-tag` which inserts a tag of choice and one or more attributes. My question is this:

How can I insert a tag with `sgml-tag` and skip insertion of an attribute. For instance, if I call the function interactively trying to insert a `p-tag`, I am not able to exit the insertion process without entering an attribute. Using `C-g` seems to abort the process, resulting in a broken opening tag.

Is there a way of entering a tag without attribute(s)? I have not found an answer in the EMACS [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/HTML-Mode.html).

Comment: Just pressing return (`RET`) at the prompt for the attribute will insert the tag without attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! The problem is that pressing return only picks one of several attributes among a set of attributes.I finally figured out why: ivy-mode. Not a problem with ido-mode. I'll see if I can figure out how to suppress ivy's eagerness in supplying attributes.

Comment: If you've answered your question, post that as an answer and mark it as solution when you're able to.

Comment: Thank's for your opinion! I'm slightly confused. Maybe you can clarify: My reputation is not high enough to vote. Can I mark my own answer as a solution? Appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in my comment, the problem seemed to relate to [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), a fantastic generic completion mechanism for Emacs.

Somehow i failed to realise what was going on: ivy was doing its job and providing candidates for completion. The solution is readily available in the [Ivy user manual](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-single-selection-action-then-exit-minibuffer): `ivy-immediate-done`, which is bound to `C-M-j`, breaks out of the attribute candidate provision and inserts the requested tag without further ado.

Comment: Can you mark your answer as the solution?